# Handle image loading in React

Tags: javascript, css, image, reactjs

I'm using this code to load images

```
{Image} from 'react-bootstrap';
<Image src={res.imgUrl} className={styles.image} onError={(e)=>{e.target.src="/defaultImage.png"}} responsive thumbnail />
<Label bsStyle="primary" className={styles.price}}>{Price} &#8364;</Label>
```

Here is the css code for the label

```
.price {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      font-size: 0.95em;
    }
```

It works fine. But during loading the "Label"-Element shows up not nicely, since there is no image yet that has been loaded and it have not enough place to show up.

Is there a nice solution for this?

Thanks!

PS: It looks like this during loading

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple solution is to leverage the `onLoad` event, and a `didLoad` flag to delay rendering the image until it is fully loaded.

```
class Example extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            didLoad: false
        }
    }

    onLoad = () => {
        this.setState({
            didLoad: true
        })
    }


    render() {
        const style = this.state.didLoad ? {} : {visibility: 'hidden'}
        return (
            <img style={style} src={this.props.src} onLoad={this.onLoad} />
        )
    }
}
```

As requested, an example using **hooks**:

```
function VisImgExample({src}) {
  const [didLoad, setLoad] = React.useState(false);

  const style = didLoad ? {} : {visibility: 'hidden'};

  return <img style={style} src={src} onLoad={() => setLoad(true)} />;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot. I had the hope that there was a way to use the alt attribute. But this solution works fine. In my example I had to add                             {this.state.didLoad && <Label bsStyle="primary"  className={`${styles.label} ${styles.price}`}>{PREIS} &#8364;</Label> }, since the label did the trouble. Manipulating the styles didn't work that well, since I use react-bootrstrap and it would overwrite the complete style of the image component.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice this was for React & not React Native. Anyway, thanks for the hooks answer. For React Native, I had to change `visibility: 'hidden'` to `opacity: 0`. I also had to add a `key={didLoad}` prop to the `<Image>`.